# Jquery DropDownlist Select Value Function efficiency

Tags: jquery

## I would like to get this function to just pick the selected value directly rather than doing a check separately:

```
 $(".Dir_SearchType").each(function() {         
    if ($(this).is(':checked')){            
        window.location = 'index.php?' + id + '=' + info + '&ms=' + $(this).val();
    } else {
        window.location = 'index.php?' + id + '=' + info + '&ms=' + '<?php echo $pageOrg->getDefaultVB(); ?>';
    }
```

===========================================================================================
Any thoughts on how I can access the selected value directly?

Comment: can you share your html too?

Comment: How are you calling this? does this happend on the page load?

Comment: How your post connected with question title?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just filter out the unchecked elements?

```
$(".Dir_SearchType:checked").each(function() {
    window.location = ...;
}
```

Also, just a tip, for simple properties, instead of something like `$(this).is(":checked");` you can just use the DOM element reference `this.checked` it's faster and easier than jQuery.

Comment: Yes, but again you could just use the DOM reference and do `this.value`